# getimagesize return array even the file doesn't exists

Tags: php, getimagesize

I have images with user id (eg.**img299** etc.). This images are already place in a folder called **images**. When user login, I create image name with user id like this **img299**(**299** is the user id).

After I create image name, I need to check this image name is already exists or not in **images** folder. If image is exists, I want to show that image and if not just only show underline.

So, I try like this:

```
$filename = "img".$userID;
$filepath = "http://www.example.com/images/".$filename.".gif";

var_dump(getimagesize($filepath));//for testing

if(getimagesize($filepath)) {
    echo "<img src = 'http://www.example.com/images/".$filename.".gif'>";                              
} else {
    echo "____________________________";
}
```

The above code is work if the image is exists. But the problem is, if the image is not exists under images folder, **getimagesize** return like this:

[image: getimagesize return array]

So, the result is true and that line **echo "http://www.example.com/images/".$filename.".gif'>";** is work and image can't show correctly.

That is the problem for me. I want to show only underline if the image is not exists.

So, I also try with **if(file_exists($filepath))** and it always return false even if the image is exists.

How can I check image is exists or not. I will appreciate  any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) with the *local path to the file* to check if it exists. I.e. do not use the full URL (example.com/...) but the path on the filesystem relative to the file you're executing (e.g. `../images/filename.png`).

Comment: @Martijin I also try with `if(file_exists($filepath))` and it always return false even if the image is exists.

Comment: @Martijin Yes. One more thing is, when I try as you said, `file_exists()` return true for some image file and some are return false. I don't know why. Please guide me.